# Error while Recovering deleted files using Foremost

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, data-recovery

I am facing this below error message while trying to recover deleted videos using *foremost*. I am not sure how to fix this, would really appreciate any help.

```
$ sudo foremost -i /dev/sda5 -t wmv -o . -T

Processing: /dev/sda5
|******************************WMV err num_header_objs=0 headerSize=0
WMV err num_header_objs=0 headerSize=0
*************************************WMV err num_header_objs=14978577 headerSize=14963569906419540224
*WMV err num_header_objs=16 headerSize=602285480705
***WMV err num_header_objs=-1 headerSize=18446744073709486080
WMV err num_header_objs=1870031190 headerSize=4210425200337118550
WMV err num_header_objs=-1 headerSize=18446744073709486080
WMV err num_header_objs=1870031190 headerSize=4210425200337118550
**WMV err num_header_objs=2097152 headerSize=70368744177792
*WMV err num_header_objs=119153010 headerSize=7012667750162976000
*********WMV err num_header_objs=1663988589 headerSize=8606505831878652775
WMV err num_header_objs=108942 headerSize=5
******************************************************WMV err num_header_objs=1162622513 headerSize=3262387707338293248
WMV err num_header_objs=1380142166 headerSize=0
**********WMV err num_header_objs=1313407028 headerSize=8101131813384945782
***********************WMV err num_header_objs=1974609462 headerSize=49407
WMV err num_header_objs=1974609462 headerSize=49407
**********************WMV err num_header_objs=119153010 headerSize=7012667750162976000
WMV err num_header_objs=1885958755 headerSize=6006394881512120611
**************************************************WMV err num_header_objs=1974609462 headerSize=43336
WMV err num_header_objs=1974609462 headerSize=43336
****WMV err num_header_objs=1179472430 headerSize=792599445374242047
**********WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
********************************************************************WMV err num_header_objs=203445093 headerSize=1283430543591726241
************************WMV err num_header_objs=-1442784858 headerSize=1283357180869879345
WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
***************************WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
WMV err num_header_objs=1635021921 headerSize=2334106421097295433
*WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
WMV err num_header_objs=-1442784858 headerSize=1283357180869879345
*****WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
**WMV err num_header_objs=-1073683314 headerSize=1283430543591726241
*************************WMV err num_header_objs=544175136 headerSize=7310859660593556307
****************WMV err num_header_objs=48 headerSize=34
WMV err num_header_objs=0 headerSize=180393692416
************************************************WMV err num_header_objs=298821959 headerSize=10136437970375278594
***************************************************|
```

Comment: @Rinzwind: do you know anygood recovery software to recover wmv files?
I tried using photorec as well but it didn't recover a single video file. It was a highly recommended software but I found it pretty useless. :(
I am really stuck, I accidently deleted them and now I am unable to recover them. :(

Comment: https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec it is in their list. The thing with recovery is: if the disk got changed you lost that file forever.

Comment: If I read this correctly: https://fossies.org/dox/foremost-1.5.7/extract_8c_source.html that software did not find the header of the WMV.

Comment: @Rinzwind, yea, I tried recovering again using Photorec, but this time I only selected a single extension, it did recover the files but the problem is, none of the files that it has recovered are working. almost every single file just plays for a few seconds and then stops working.
so like I said, photorec is pretty useless, it does work wonders for photos though as It recovered practically every single photo that I had deleted with no issues with them whatsoever. but it's video recovery su.cks.